# Does Google have a WebRequest limit?

Tags: webrequest, google-image-search

I made a Tool in C# which gets random images from google images via WebRequests.
My question now is: is there a limit on webrequests iam allowed to take in a speicifc amount of time? I dont want to ddos Google and want to play after rules.

Anybody know something?

Comment: Are you using API ?

Comment: @Youssef13 no, just normal WebRequests

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit basically:
1,000 free requests per 24 hour period, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests. If your app exceeds the initial limit, the app will start failing.

### [Google link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/limits:

> The Search Analytics resource enforces the following limits:
>
> > Per-site limit (calls querying the same site):
> >
> > - 5 QPS
> > - 200 QPM
> >
> > Per-user limit (calls made by the same user):
> >
> > - 5 QPS
> > - 200 QPM
> >
> > Per-project limit (calls made using the same Developer Console key):
> >
> > - 100,000,000 QPD
> >
> > Example
> >
> > - User A can make up to 5 QPS combined to her 3 websites.
> > - Users A and B can make up to 5 QPS combined to their one website.
>
> All other resources
>
> > Per-user limit (calls made by the same user):
> >
> > - 20 QPS
> > - 200 QPM
> >
> > Per-project limit (calls made using the same Developer Console key):
> >
> > - 100,000,000 QPD

- QPS: Queries / second
- QPM: Queries / minute
- QPD: Queries / day